# I got a new Macbook.I installed lowbrow and Git but I cannot

Tags: github

in my GitHub account I have more Repository. I got a new Macbook. I installed Howbrew and Git . but I cannot contact my local with my GitHub profile. How can I make that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: *homebrew I wrote wrong that

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your SSH key of your new Macbook in your Github profile?

If not then here's the way: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

After doing this activity, you'll be able to access your repositories from your local environment in Macbook

Comment: thanh you so much

Comment: Maybe you can verify my answer so that people do not post